# Difference in gcc on linux and windows

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a difference b/w gcc on linux and windows For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i=5;
  printf("%d  %d ",++i,++i);
}
```

On Windows it is **6 5** On Linux it comes to be **7 7**

Comment: I am guessing the `++j` is really `++i` which in that case makes this undefined behavior since you are not allowed to modify the same variable more than once within a sequence point.

Comment: Uh huh. And what is j?

Comment: Are they the same version of GCC?

Comment: Your code has a bug. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz incidentally, osx gives `6 7` when fixing the bug

Comment: Though mine Gives [Error] stackoverflow.c:6: error: `j' was not declared in this scope.
That is undefined behavior. There are no guarantee of what will happen at all both in Windows & Linux .

Comment: Just see compiler warning: `operation on 'i' may be undefined`.

Comment: @Nope -- As alluded to by Shafik Yaghmour, try doing a google search on: sequence points C programming

Comment: @Moderators - it looks like this question has been updated - I think it is now a perfect valid question which could do with a good answer.

Comment: The answer here will basically come down to the fact that it entirely undefined what the compiler should do here.  So different compilers, different versions of the same compiler and even the same version of same compiler on different arch/OS can have different behaviour.  The only thing we can be sure of is that the value of i *will* be 7 *after* the printf() statement.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260171/1708801) for more details.